# foreign key relationships on delete cascade on update cascade

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server 2012 , I have table `PurchaseReturn(VendorId,PurchaseOrderId)`. The column 'Vendorid' is a foreign key relationship to  Vendor(VendorId) and 'Purchaseorderid' is to Purchaseorder(purchaseorderi).
Now my target is to set type of foreign key for 'VendorId' as 'On delete Set Null on Update Cascade' but For 'purchaseorderid' it should be 'On delete CasCade On Update Cascade'.

But when i have created FK for VendorId and trying to make it for PurchaseOrderId by following query:

```
alter table PurchaseReturn add constraint FK_PR_PORD foreign key (Purchaseorderid) references PurchaseOrder(Purchaseorderid) on delete cascade ON UPDATE CASCADE ';
```

an errors appears like this:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_PR_PORD' on table 'PurchaseReturn' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

What is the problem?... plz help thanks in advance 
This is the create table query alonq with constraints

```
USE [AsifTraders]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PurchaseReturn]    Script Date: 24-Sep-14 11:46:39 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseReturn](
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseReturnId] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VendorId] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ReturnType] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Deduction] [numeric](15, 0) NULL,
    [ProductQuantity] [numeric](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseValue] [numeric](12, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ReturnValue] [numeric](15, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Paid] [numeric](15, 0) NULL,
    [PBalance] [numeric](15, 0) NULL,
    [NBalance] [numeric](15, 0) NULL,
    [JEntryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PURCHASEORDERID] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PurchaseReturn] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PurchaseReturnId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseReturn]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PR_VEN] FOREIGN KEY([PURCHASEORDERID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] ([PurchaseOrderId])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseReturn] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PR_VEN]
GO
```

This is the query for PurhcaseOrder

```
USE [AsifTraders]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PurchaseOrder]    Script Date: 24-Sep-14 11:56:53 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder](
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [PurchaseOrderId] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [JEntryId] [int] NULL,
    [VendorId] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [PurchaseType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ItemQuantity] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [DeleiveryCharges] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Discount] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Total] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Paid] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [PBalance] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [NBalance] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PurchaseOrderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_purch_ven] FOREIGN KEY([VendorId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Vendor] ([VendorId])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_purch_ven]
GO
```

Comment: So, I'm lost. The table definition for PurchaseReturn already has a foreign key constraint to PurchaseOrder set to cascade. Are you trying to add another one? Why? Are you trying to change it? It seems to be named incorrectly (it has `VEN` in the name). Drop it before you try to fix it or add different constraints that will currently point to the same table...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, first foreign key is created on Column 'VendorId'. But I want to add another FK on column 'PurchaseorderId' that is refrenced to Purchaseorder(purchaseOrderId)

Comment: Uh, no, the first foreign key is NOT created on column `VendorId`. Did you look at it? `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseReturn]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PR_VEN] FOREIGN KEY([PURCHASEORDERID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] ([PurchaseOrderId])`

Comment: Ohh... thats a mistake.. but well then now i would like to create a FK on Vendor(VendorId) what in this case? I am actually doing this and getting error